# How to serialize two nested django tables?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

iI've updated the post and pasted the complete code. can any fix the code for me. actually i want to POST data with album name and multiple images adn serialize the both and at POST request I want the whole submitted data. means.
{
name : My favourite songs list
media: [
{
media : filename1,
media : filename2
}
]
}

```
#views.py
@api_view(['POST'])
def addAlbum(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = AlbumSerializer(data=request.data)
    albums = request.data.pop('media')
    if albums:
        name = Album.objects.create(name=request.data['name'])
        if serializer.is_valid():
            for file in albums:
                AlbumImages.objects.create(media = file, album = name)
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response("Please upload the files", status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

return Response("Not found", status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


#serializers.py
class AlbumImagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = AlbumImages
    fields = "__all__"

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
albumimages = AlbumImagesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Album
    fields = "__all__"

#models.py
class Album(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class AlbumImages(models.Model):
album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='albumimages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
media = models.ImageField(upload_to='album/images')

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f'Files of ' + self.album.name
```

Album is being generated, files are being associated with album table, but the question is how i'll serialize both tables to show response on post request. waiting for help.

Comment: On a side note, you should copy-paste your code instead of taking screenshots, so it's easier for us to reuse it in our answers.

Comment: @TartineThomas I've pasted the code. can you fix the things. actually, I am stuck.

Comment: Could you please add the current response returned by the API ?

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted your code a little bit but it wasn´t tested.
If you don´t want to adjusted the `album`-`ForeignKey` field you must change the behavoiur of saving instead of using `.objects.create()`. It should work.

You wrote a lot of validations. Your serializer can do that. You can use `extra_kwargs = {'media': {'required': True}` at your `AlbumImage`-serialzer for example. If you need more explenation don´t hasitate to ask.

```
   album = Album(**validated_data)`
   album.albumimages = albumimages_set
   album.save()
```

```py
#views.py
class AlbumView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        resp = Response()
        serializer = AlbumSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            resp.data = serializer.save()
        else:
            resp.status_code = HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            resp.data = serializer.errors
        return resp

#serializers.py
class AlbumImagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AlbumImages
        fields = "__all__"

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    albumimages = AlbumImagesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = "__all__"
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        albumimages = validated_data.pop('albumimages')
        albumimages_set = [AlbumImages.objects.create(**element) for element in albumimages ]
            
        album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
        album.albumimages.set(albumimages_set)
        album.save()
        
        return album 

#models.py
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class AlbumImages(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='albumimages', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    media = models.ImageField(upload_to='album/images')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Files of ' + self.album.name
```